# Techniques for getting values of ES6 Map with regex keys

Tags: ecmascript-6

Is there a more efficient way to reproduce the following code, which involves retrieving a capture group match from a map with keys composed of regular expression objects and values composed of functions accepting the results of matching a key against the regex?

```
function getFromRegexKeys(key, map) {
  for (let [re, val] of map.entries()) {
    if (re.test(key)) {
      return val(key.match(re));
    }
  }
}

const map = new Map([
  [/^foo\/(.+)$/, matchResults => matchResults[1]],
  [/^bar\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)$/, matchResults => matchResults[2]],
]);

getFromRegexKeys('foo/', map); // === undefined
getFromRegexKeys('foo/quuz', map); // === 'quuz'
getFromRegexKeys('bar/baz/qux/quz', map); // === 'qux'
```

Comment: Use the initial part before the 1st slash as key, and map those to pairs of *pattern, fun* ?

Comment: I don't understand. Care to provide some code?

Answer (score 2):

Don't run `test` *and* `match`, which applies the regex twice. Just do

```
function getFromRegexKeys(key, map) {
  for (const [re, val] of map.entries()) {
    const res = re.exec(key); // or `key.match(re)`
    if (res) return val(res);
  }
}
```